# Please suggest one free log manager which will help me to audit all system and services logs in organized format?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, log, logging, system-monitor

I have Ubuntu server 11.10 but without GUI, so it is fine even if that suggest a software or something like that which will intern help me do that. it will be grate if that software can export logs in excel sheet format, using some command or something.

Thanks a lot in advance..

Rishee :)

Comment: Logwatch - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logwatch

Comment: Hi Bodhi, Thanks for that link. I have installed it but, I am not sure, how to use it. So can you help me on that as well. Thanking you!! Regards- Rishee :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking for the auditing software for a long long time. I have found that KSystemLog i.e. by canonical is a good software available as of now. So enjoy it ... thank you all for supporting and please let me know if you find any better tool or software. :) Thanks a lot!!